# How to configure ingress with multiple nodes?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, devops

So, in my case I have 3 nodes in my cluster (1 master node, and 2 worker nodes). I want to configure an ingress, so that one specific route reaches a service on the first worker node, and the other specific route reaches a service on the second worker node. However, that is not possible. When I configure ingress, it is being assigned the address of master node. Therefore, the routing works only with the services available on master node. How can I make my ingress to see services of other nodes as well?

Comment: If this is about Kubernetes, a Service isn't "on a node" in any meaningful way.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; what do the Service and Ingress objects look like?  Are you having trouble configuring the cluster so the ingress system works properly, or having trouble writing the ingress rules?

Answer (score 0):

> However, that is not possible. When I configure ingress, it is being assigned the address of master node.

As a general rule, when configuring an ingress, we would see the IP addresses for the nodes hosting your ingress controllers, in their status. This sounds normal.

Eg, with 3 replicas of the nginx ingress controller:

```
$> kubectl  get ingress -n logging
NAME             HOSTS               ADDRESS                                  PORTS
kibana-kube      kibana.example.com  10.42.253.13,10.42.253.14,10.42.253.15   80, 443
```

Those have nothing to do with SDN IP. They're here to let you know where to connect, as a client/external to cluster.

> Therefore, the routing works only with the services available on master node.

Now this has nothing to do with your ingress controller, and rather suggests your SDN does not work. Which you should be able to confirm, opening a shell on your ingress controller (or any other pod running on that master), and trying to connect the ClusterIP or Pod IP directly.

If you didn't deploy an SDN yet: you should

If you don't know which SDN runs in your cluster: check

Knowing which SDN you use: check health for those pods. If there's no obvious logs or events suggesting something's wrong, refer to your SDN docs.

We can't guess much from what you told us so far. Amend your question with your findings.

Comment: Yes, I am testing that in my local machine for learning purposes. And I have created 3 worker nodes. First node is responsible for back-end. Second node is responsible for front-end. And third node is responsible for DB. I want to keep my master node clean. So, after this, I wanted to create an ingress so that I can map url to the services running on different nodes. But I cant.

Comment: Why the separation of infrastructure? If one of those nodes goes down, you lose all of your back-end, front-end, or database instances. Kubernetes will handle the routing between pods on different nodes for you.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I thought we have to manually seperate each node for one and only type of work. Now I got that kubernetes will itself manage that. Thank you so much, now everything is clear.